# Do I need Java to run/install Minecraft mods and/or Minecraft Forge?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I am trying to figure out how to download and run Minecraft mods.  I know I have to first load Minecraft Forge.  I am wondering if I have to have Java to do this??  I do not have Java on my computer and would like to keep it that way if at all possible.  I am running Windows 8.1 and have Minecraft 1.8.4.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you need java in order to use forge. There is also another conflict with your question. Java is required to play Minecraft itself. So if you're playing Minecraft you have java. Here are the requirements for Minecraft. 

[Minecraft Minimum Requirements](https://help.mojang.com/customer/portal/articles/325948-minecraft-system-requirements)
**Minimum Requirements:**

- CPU: Intel Pentium D or AMD Athlon 64 (K8) 2.6 GHz
- RAM: 2GB
- GPU (Integrated): Intel HD Graphics or AMD (formerly ATI) Radeon HD Graphics with OpenGL 2.1.
- GPU (Discrete): Nvidia GeForce 9600 GT or AMD Radeon HD 2400 with OpenGL 3.1.
- HDD: At least 200MB for Game Core and Other Files.
- **Java 6 Release 45**

Comment: The only Java that I have/am running is the standalone that was installed with the new Mojang launcher.  It is solely used for Minecraft -- it is downloaded and stored with the Minecraft launcher.  It is virtually invisible and inaccessible to the rest of my system - therefore my system is not open to Java vulnerabilities.

Comment: Also, I asked the same question on the Forge forum and was told that I could use the slim JRE that the Mojang launcher downloaded but they will not support nor give me any instruction.  I have tried both the .jar and .exe intalls and neither will open.  When I click the .jar file -- computer prompts that I don't have the app to run it.  When I click the .exe file - message pops up that I need JRE in order to run.

Comment: Well sadly this is outside of the scope that I was trying anwser. Also this is now outside the scope of Arqade for help installing a slim JRE isn't related to gaming. Sorry i couldn't help.

Comment: @Leslie Unrelated to your question, but your attempts to protect yourself from Java are misguided. By far the only attack vector worth noticing for Java is if you use it in your browser. Having it installed on your system is not going to cause you any trouble.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I think there are concerns if you running a Minecraft server exposed to the internet.

Comment: @JonathanHartley That's true if you're running anything at all exposed to a network. It has nothing to do with Java itself.

Comment: Hey @ChrisHayes. So that I understand: Running an app using old Java with known exploits, exposed to the internet, is fine? Is that what you're saying? I wouldn't have expected it.

Answer (score 0):

### 1) If you can run vanilla, then you can run mods

If you can run vanilla MC with that your strange version of Java, then definetly you can run the modded MC too. However the installation can be problem for you, because installation process needs Java to run the installator.

However if you are really into "Java is dangerous", why you won't use Virtual Machine with system installation and Java installation? Then you will be good. You don't even need to use Windows, some tiny linux installation should not eat so much memory.

Or the easiest oldschool solution - make an installation on another PC with Java and then just copy the whole folder with Forge (/versions/...).

PS: Mods need to have more RAM, than vanilla MC. 1GB is not enough, normal mods add WAY more things than vanilla has. So if your strange Java version cannot support more(for sure you need 64bit version), you still will have problems.
And - I think that Java is not that dangerous at all...but let's not discuss that here.

---

### 2) How to run it at all:

If you managed to put the new folder into your `.minecraft/versions/` folder, which will contain bins with Forge installation , then you just need to add new profile in launcher, you should be able to choose the version you added. But be sure that :

Let that profile to have Forced directory, then create for it some. It will contain MODS, CONFIG and other folders, so vanilla and modded things won't interfere with each other. After first run, all subfolders should be created for you. Then just drop the mod jar files into the MODS folder and hope that your strange version of Java will be enough :)